# mysql multiple table DELETE rows syntax error

Tags: mysql

How come this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `store_catalog_product_option` 
    JOIN `store_catalog_product_option_type_value` 
WHERE `product_id`=15676 
    AND `store_catalog_product_option_type_value`.`sku` LIKE '%UNIT_%'
```

retrieve data.

But replacing

```
select *
```

with

```
delete
```

as such

```
DELETE 
FROM `store_catalog_product_option` 
    JOIN `store_catalog_product_option_type_value` 
WHERE `product_id`=15676 
    AND `store_catalog_product_option_type_value`.`sku` LIKE '%UNIT_%'
```

give syntax error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN `store_catalog_product_option_type_value` WHERE `product_id`=15676 AND `sto' at line 1

Comment: Can you post your error?

Comment: What error you are recieveing??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [multi-table deletes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html),

> For the first multiple-table syntax, only matching rows from the tables listed before the `FROM` clause are deleted. the second multiple-table syntax, only matching rows from the tables listed in the `FROM` clause (before the `USING` clause) are deleted.

```
DELETE t1, t2 FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 INNER JOIN t3
WHERE t1.id=t2.id AND t2.id=t3.id;
```

> Or:

```
DELETE FROM t1, t2 USING t1 INNER JOIN t2 INNER JOIN t3
WHERE t1.id=t2.id AND t2.id=t3.id;
```

And for `LEFT JOIN`, you should use something like

```
DELETE t1 FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id=t2.id WHERE t2.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Are there cases where the second form (with USING) does not work, or do you just prefer the first form (that does not include USING)?

Comment: For LEFT JOIN that is.

Answer (score 1):

Your JOIN should have an ON part

Answer (score 1):

You can try somthing like this:-

```
DELETE FROM `store_catalog_product_option` A
JOIN `store_catalog_product_option_type_value' B
ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE A.`product_id`=15676 
AND B.`sku` LIKE '%UNIT_%'
```

Alternatively you can use:-

```
DELETE A
FROM `store_catalog_product_option` A
JOIN `store_catalog_product_option_type_value' B
ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE A.`product_id`=15676 
AND B.`sku` LIKE '%UNIT_%'
```

...to delete only from `store_catalog_product_option`

Answer (score 0):

I needed indeed to use a multiple table syntax, including also a ON condition for the JOIN.

Since i wanted to delete rows in both tables , here is my working query, after your help:

```
 DELETE O, V FROM `store_catalog_product_option` O JOIN `store_catalog_product_option_type_value` V on O.option_id=V.option_id WHERE `product_id`=15676 AND V.`sku` LIKE '%UNIT_%'
```